# error in python with GUI file and databse sqlite3 file

Tags: python, sqlite

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Mini_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
```

This is the data base call i made and the error popping with this --

> cur=conn.execute(sql) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: teams

```
import sqlite3
    conn=sqlite3.connect('PlayerStats.db')
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.cb0)
    sql="select name from teams"
    cur=conn.execute(sql)
    team=[]
    for row in cur:
        self.cb0.addItem(row[0])
    conn.close()
```

i cant understandt this error at all `ui.setupUi(Dialog)`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
      ui = Mini_Ui()
      ui.setupUi(Dialog)
      Dialog.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also, the indentation inb the last code snippet is wrong.

Comment: The error message seems to be clear. You don't have a `teams` table in `PlayerStats.db`.

Comment: i have a teams table in my db file

Comment: Errors don't lie. If you had a `teams` table in the file, you wouldn't get that error. Check the spelling.